# How can I prevent the modeline from covering up the last line of some prompts/buffers in the bottom?

Tags: mode-line

When I use some commands that display a buffer in the bottom which prompts some additional info, my mode-line is covering up the last line (or part of it). Is there a way to turn off the mode-line in these cases, or possibly adding some additional padding to the prompting buffer so that it doesn't cover up anything important. In the screenshot you can see one such case, where it is covering the tasks when selecting a task to clock into.

EDIT: Looks like this is cause by the package spaceline-all-the-icons. Disabling that and using vanilla spaceline, it seems to work just fine. I'll report this to spaceline-all-the-icons issues.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Might be, but in what? Emacs? Powerline/Spaceline?

Comment: Bisect your init file to find out. With `emacs -Q` there is no Powerline or Spaceline etc. You are explicitly using such things. Bisect your code to find out which part causes the problem. It's quick - a binary search.

Comment: Okay, looks like this might be a bug in spaceline-all-the-icons package. I need to see if I can figure out what's causing it. Disabling that and just using the plain spaceline modeline seems to work

Comment: As you can see, that info improves your question, making it much more specific and relevant to those who might be able to help. Please integrate the info you've discovered into the framing of the question, and consider reporting the problem to the maintainer of Spaceline. Remember that comments can be deleted at any time, so try to make the question itself self-contained and as informative as possible. Thx.